# mobile landscape view Image position: absolute

Tags: html, css

```
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0,maximum-scale=1.0">
</head>

<img src="viewer.png" style="width:200; height:150; position:absolute; bottom:0; right:0;z-index:-4000;">
```

Please Help : In mobile Portrait view  position is correct. but in mobile landscape view  in middle rightside.. 
(I placed  **to view bottom** of all contents.. **no scrollbars** in portrait view)
How to fix it?

Comment: How do you want it???

Comment: i want to view it in bottom right side, but in landscape mode all other contents overlapping

Answer (score 0):

you can try this way

```css
.imgcenter{
position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 40%;
  height: 50%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://unsplash.it/200/80" alt="" class="imgcenter">
```